# Hide element when child is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, display

I need to hide div when its child element is empty. Specifically, I need to add the class .no-content if the child element is empty.

I have this code with spaces:

```
<div class="ee-posts-list">       
<div class="ee-post ">                    </div>
<div class="ee-post ">                    </div>
<div class="ee-post ">                    </div>
<div class="ee-post ">                    </div>
</div>
```

I also need to add a class if the div has no text:

```
<div class="ee-posts-list">       
<div class="ee-post no-content">                    </div>
<div class="ee-post no-content">                    </div>
<div class="ee-post no-content">                    </div>
<div class="ee-post no-content">                    </div>
</div>
```

I have a similar problem that I need to solve, and for that, I use this script:

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.ee-post').forEach(post => {
  if (!post.querySelector('.breakdance').hasChildNodes()) {
    post.classList.add('no-content');
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML.trim()`. This will get the contents with surrounding whitespace removed, so it will be empty for the blank divs in your example.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ee-post').forEach(post => {
  if (post.querySelector('.breakdance').innerHTML.trim() == '') {
    post.classList.add('no-content');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code iterate over all elements with the ee-post class and add a no-content class to any element that has no content:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ee-post').forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.innerHTML.trim() === '') {
        element.classList.add('no-content');
        console.log("class added");
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/proudhon/pen/OJoNdQd